# Asp.net MVC post action rendering 2 views at a time + intermittent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a registration form with 2 tabs. 2 tabs has are different views. When user loads registration page, page is loaded with 1st step view(index).

Once user fills data in first section and click on submit we are making post call to this action method(Index with Post). This action has return type as below

```
return View("Index_Step2");
```

Every time this working fine by loading only index_step2 when post action is triggered.

But some times it is rendering index_step2 and below index(step1 view).

We are using asp.net mvc 5.2.3 version.

Can you please suggest what can be the problem for this intermittent issue?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Registration", FormMethod.Post, new { id = 
"registrationForm" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="registration-tabs">
    <div class="step active">
        <div>
            <a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Registration")'>
                <h3 class="one">@Model.Messages["PersonalDetails"]</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step last">
        <div>
            <h3 class="two">@Model.Messages["AccountData"]</h3>
            <input type="submit" value="Account Data" class="btn style4" />
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
}
```

Post Action Index:

```
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "Input")] RegistrationForm model)
{
 //Step1 Input process and create viewModel for step2
 return View("RegistrationStep2", viewModel);
}
```

View in Step2 contains form like below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegistrationStep2", "Registration", FormMethod.Post, 
new { id = "registrationForm" }))
{
 //Form fields 
}
```

When Post Action is triggered in Step1 of this page, some times it is rendering 2 views like below

1. View RegistrationStep2 then
2. Below of this form binding RegistrationStep1 in the same view.

This issue was observed on IOS safari browser. We are trying to reproduce this again but it is coming intermittently. Due to this we are unable to provide a fix for this

Comment: Could you show some code to us?

Comment: I have added code in post